# How do I get a node on my firebase database to be updated throughout the JSON tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

My web app is based on a soccer league. I had a Javascript array of objects. Each player was an object in the array :

```
 $scope.players = [
   {name : "Yasin 'YB' Amusan", Team : "Industry", price: 8000000, position: 'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera", Team : "Industry", price: 5000000, position: 'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Femi 'Fabio' Awoniyi", Team : "Industry", price: 9000000, position: 'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Deji 'Dej' Awoniyi", Team : "Industry", price: 7000000, position: 'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Koye 'K10' Kekere-Ekun", Team : "Industry", price: 9000000, position:'midfielder', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Teni 'Teezee' Zacchaeus", Team : "Industry", price: 6000000, position:'hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
   {name : "Bolaji 'Boj' Odojukan", Team : "Industry", price: 7000000, position:'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'}
 ];
```

However, when the number of players increased to about 47, I decided to use firebase as my backend. So i made a JSON file of the players and imported it to the firebase database:

```
 {
"players" : [
   {"name" : "Yasin 'YB' Amusan", 
    "Team" : "Industry",
    "price": 8000000, 
    "position": "forward", 
   "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png", 
    "goals": 0, 
    "assists" : 0, 
    "Y" : 0, 
    "R" : 0},
   {"name" : "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera",
    "Team" : "Industry", 
    "price": 5000000, 
    "position": "defender",
    "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png",
    "goals": 0, 
    "assists" : 0,
    "Y" : 0,
    "R" : 0},
   {"name" : "Femi 'Fabio' Awoniyi",
    "Team" : "Industry",
    "price": 9000000,
    "position": "defender",
    "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png",
    "goals": 0, 
    "assists" : 0, 
    "Y" : 0, 
    "R" : 0},
   {"name" : "Deji 'Dej' Awoniyi",
    "Team" : "Industry",
    "price": 7000000,
    "position": "forward",
     "image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png",
    "goals": 0, 
    "assists" : 0, 
    "Y" : 0, 
    "R" : 0}
  ....etc
   ]
   }
```

The players are listed out for the user to select from using :

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('players');
 $scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);
  console.log ($scope.players);
```

When Each user picks the players they want, it gets posted to a child node under the "users" node called 'gameweek 1' and the respective points are allocated based on each player's performance/ stats.

MY PROBLEM

My problem is how to update the player stats in the 'Players' node in the database such that it updates in the 'gameweek' child node under each user's selection in the "user" node.

Comment: Since the paths you want to update multiple paths at same time you are looking for firebase.database().ref().update() which can be found here( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update )

Comment: @user7814783 I was thinking more like updating it manually in the firebase console itself. Is that not possible?

Comment: no manually thats not possible,you have to change it everywhere, otherwise you can consider using cloud functions to trigger a function  when a node in the database is changed and apply changes in the nodes where you want